# Why is my message consumer not receiving every other message?

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I've written some code to push TestMessages onto a queue using ActiveMQ running on a Glassfish 4 server
If I send as consecutive messages "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" 
I only receive "A", "C", "E"

Does anyone have any idea why?

Message producer

```
public void sendMessage(String msg) {
    try {
        if (session == null) {
            session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            queue = session.createQueue(QUEUE_NAME);
        }
        messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
        Message message = createMessage(msg);
        messageProducer.send(message);
    } catch (NamingException nex) {
        System.out.println("Messager - naming exception" + nex.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (JMSException jex) {
        System.out.println("Messager - JMS exception" + jex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Message Consumer

```
public class Listener extends Thread implements MessageListener {           
    private void run() {
        try {
            connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(AMQ_USER, AMQ_PASS, url);
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            queue = session.createQueue(QUEUE_NAME);
            consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
            consumer.setMessageListener(this);
            connection.start();
        } catch (NamingException nex) {
            log.error("Error in run()", nex);
        } catch (JMSException jex) {
            log.error("Error in run()", jex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            try {
                TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                if (textMessage != null) {
                    System.out.println(textMessage.getText());
                }
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance
Mark

Comment: Sanity check: Are you sure you have only one consumer? No exceptions? How about messages sent after a particular period of time? No exception queues? What happens to the B, D and F messages - are they consumed/not processed?

Comment: Did you try setting the prefetch buffer to your consumer? And do you have only one consumer? If there are more than one, may be you need to kill first consumer so that other consumers could consume other messages. ActiveMQ does this to guarantee maximum thorough put

Comment: It sounds like you've got two consumers, and messages are getting round-robined between the two.  On the web console for the broker, go to the Queues page and look at the Number Of Consumers column for your queue; I'd bet it's 2.  If so, click the Active Consumers link to get more details about the other one, and then try to figure out where it's connecting from and kill it.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions; I never really resolved the problem but the project got shelved anyway. I did write a different simple consumer and it promptly received all the missing messages. As the consumer was for a Jira plugin, I can only guess that the plugin sdk or the Jira server was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer here is that you have more than one consumer running on that destination.  Whenever there are more than one consumer for a Queue the messages are load balanced between them.  You can connect to the broker via JMX or using the Web Console and check the subscriptions on the Queue to see how many there are.